# API for a Google Keep app?

Tags: google-keep

Is there coming API for a Google Keep app?

Would be cool to be able to create a widget for desktop.

Comment: How is this not constructive?

Comment: This is a very good question upvoted 24 times as of totday.

Comment: The answer is here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196238/is-there-a-google-keep-api). There is no API :(