# Is there a Google Keep API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-keep

Is there a API for Google Keep? I want to make a windows 8 app for Google Keep, so that it synchronizes with your phone.

I looked into the Drive SDK because Google Keep is a extension of Google Drive, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Keep is NOT an extension of Drive. Where does it say so?

Comment: The url from Google Keep; https://drive.google.com/keep/. Otherwise the service would have got another subdomain or something

Comment: How about http://keep.google.com ?

Comment: FYI, I think google is currently developing an API. The web interface uses `https://clients6.google.com/notes/v1/` to receive and update notes.

Comment: Sorry but how is this question "off-topic" exactly?

Comment: Issue posted on google code: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3477

Comment: @still_learning - https://clients6.google.com/notes/v1/ is broken

Comment: any news on the subject ?

Comment: this topic especially actual after last android app update. now i want to develop my own app with "quick note" feature and more handy labels management

Comment: check this out https://github.com/kiwiz/gkeepapi. Its unofficial API client. handle with care

Comment: update 09/2018, i guess since you have the icon of Keep in Gmail, that means there should be an api for that, just not released for the public

Comment: There's an API now: https://developers.google.com/keep/api

Comment: @FlorianBachmann would you mind adding that as an answer? I'll tag that as the accepted answer then.

Comment: I'd love to, but I can't, because the question is "Closed. This question does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines. It is not currently accepting answers."

Answer (score 160, accepted):

UPDATE: yes, Google released a public REST API for Keep. Here's the [public documentation](https://developers.google.com/keep/api/reference/rest/).

Comment: any updates for this?

Comment: I monitored with Charles proxy, got the URLs and so on, but the problem is that there are some tokens and IDs that you need to know how to generate it, and only Google does.

Comment: Their typical MO for their APIs is to use OAuth, so I would bet that that would be the token exchanges you observed...

Comment: @JeremyFelix yes, but you must write the "permissions" you want the user to accept, and we can't solicitate the Keep permission

Comment: Google keep is a great idea but lack the option of integrating it to custom tools (emacs/browser extensions/raspberry pi applications/etc) makes it's usefulness limited for power users.

Comment: I've just created a petition! @pinoyyid Please support it adding the link to the accepted answer: http://bit.ly/keep-api-petition

Comment: Someone has made an unofficial API: https://github.com/kiwiz/gkeepapi/

Comment: Would be nice if the API would allow tracking tags, for example "todo"

Comment: As "official" as this is - keep in mind that this is only for enterprise accounts (not the general public). See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209652471

Answer (score 57):

No there's not and developers still don't know why google doesn't pay attention to this request!

As you can see in **[this link](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3477)** it's one of the most popular issues with many stars in google code but still no response from google! You can also add stars to this issue, maybe google hears that!

Comment: How can we contact Google so that they can given an answer?

Comment: @BrunoLemos : I am 99% sure it's seen by now ! because it's in top10 issues right now and Google always pays attention to issues.but i don't know how to contact directly and what's their answer :(

Comment: It may have been seen, but not by the correct people... this suggestion is not a "google app script issue", also google code will be disabled this month.

Comment: They're just waiting when IT-community reverse-engineered Google Keep API and write python library by itself so they wont pay for this one cent.

Comment: This and [Google Voice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1668619/1739000) they are just ignoring... maybe it is time to move on to Zoho or some other system...

Answer (score 15):

I have been waiting to see if Google would open a Keep API.  When I discovered Google Tasks, and saw that it had an Android app, web app, and API, I converted over to Tasks.  This may not directly answer your question, but it is my solution to the Keep API problem.

Tasks doesn't have a reminder alarm exactly like Keep.  I can live without that if I also connect with the Calendar API.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/

Comment: Which app do you have in mind? I looked in Google Play and did not find any from Google.

Comment: The Android app I am using is Tasks from Team Tasks.  There is also a free version called "Tasks Free".

Comment: Just wanted to mention that unlike Google Keep, Google Tasks don't allow image attachments, which is why I'm still hoping (against hope) for a Google Keep API.

Comment: There is now an official Google Tasks app for Android - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.tasks&hl=en_US

Comment: Task doesn't even have a widget. It can't really replace Keep - for me, at least. It depends on what you're trying to achieve, I guess.