# Is there a public Google API to access reminders set in Google Now or Google Keep?

Tags: google-api, reminders, google-now, google-keep

The time and location-based reminders in Google Now and Google Keep are different from Google Calendar event reminders. Is there a public API to access these event reminders in Now and Keep?

Answer (score 5):

There's no public API for either of these Google services.

More info on the lack of a Keep API [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196238/is-there-a-google-keep-api).