# How to create a Reminder (not Event) in Calendar programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I want to create a [reminder](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327) in Google Calendar from my Android app.

Creating events is well-documented, there’s a Calendar content provider for that. However there seems to be no content provider contract for these standalone reminders (not to be confused with event reminders, aka event notifications).

In the app, "Reminders" is listed as a separate calendar along "Events", but when I query the `CalendarContract.Calendars` table, it’s not on the list. Querying the `CalendarContract.Events` also doesn’t list reminder events. So I guess they’re stored somehow differently, yet I cannot find any info on that.

Is there a way to create these reminders programmatically?

Comment: My guess is that you would have to use some Google Calendar-specific API, whether from Play Services (don't think there is one) or standard Web APIs.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh wow, the legend himself! So, after some further searching, I found that despite it being a cross-application feature, there's no API [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294548) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728176), and there's a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760283) for that

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some more looking, answering my own question.

There’s no way to do this. Despite those reminders being a cross-application feature, there's no API to access them.

There's a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760283) for this.

My question basically duplicates questions: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294548) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728176), I didn't find them because they mentioned other apps, which share the same reminders with Calendar.