# JavaScript: which JS framework Google Keep use?

Tags: javascript, google-keep

I'm just curious, which JS framework Google Keep use? I can't find any mention about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say 100% what they use since (to my knowledge) it isn't exactly out there; but you can look into other libraries which achieve very similar layouts like: [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), [Salvattore](http://salvattore.com/), etc... There is a good chance Google is either extending functionality from that, or using it themselves.

Also to add to this question, look into the stackoverflow question I found from another user: [Is there a Google Keep API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196238/is-there-a-google-keep-api)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: An answer is a way to provide guidance that is actionable to a question, which is what I have provided here. The fact a question such as this one does not have an exact 'there it is' answer, means that such question requires an answer with guidance. Furthermore note how my answer does not critique nor requests clarification from the OP