# Is there a Google Keep API and/or a Google library/API that will let me programatically access Keep notes in a *nix script?

Tags: api, google-keep

Before anyone says this is a duplicate, I did see an older question but it was from 2013 so I thought it time to ask a new one.

[Is there a Google Keep API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196238/is-there-a-google-keep-api)

My end goal is to have an hourly script running on my server that finds all new Keep notes and sends me an e-mail. I'm not having much luck finding any APIs that will let me do this?

Comment: What do you think of Google Tasks?  It has an Android App, Web App, and API.  It's basically the same except you cannot set the time of the alarm.  If I need a timed alarm, I'll pair it with the Calendar API.

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock I liked Google Keep API cause the iOS app has a audio recorder widget on the notification drawer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is one available now

https://developers.google.com/keep/api

Comment: It's enterprise only though. As of date to be precise.

Answer (score 2):

No, right now there isn't one, hope google releases one.

I made a little python script to scrape all the data from the keep.google.com

you can find the github project [here](https://github.com/darshkpatel/GoogleKeep_Backup)