# API access to Google Home Shopping List (shoppinglist.google.com)?

Tags: google-api, actions-on-google

The Google Home assistant has a default feature called Shopping List, that lets you keep a shopping list using the Google Assistant. Using the [web UI](https://shoppinglist.google.com) it is possible to create named lists, share them with others, check items etc.

I have searched for this unsuccessfully: is there any way to access these features or just access the shopping list data through an API, getting user permission using OAuth? Any docs, samples?

Comment: There isn't an API, but you can use Google Takeout and only check the Google Assistant lists and stuff box. Maybe this might help: https://gist.github.com/stewartmcgown/7f5dcbf4ccd385637786f9581b620e6a

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately at this time there's no API for Google Shopping (or for Google Keep, which is fairly similar)

[Is there a Google Keep API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196238/is-there-a-google-keep-api)

Answer (score 1):

Also looking for the same. Have been browsing around with no results. Wrote them feedback but I doubt that they will do anything as the page seems so empty...

Although I found that Amazon Alexa has all the needed documentation to access shopping lists and todo lists: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/access-the-alexa-shopping-and-to-do-lists.html

I think its shamefull for me, just this weekend I already gave up of using Google TTS and started using (Amazon) AWS Polly for the simplicity of installation and use, and now it seems Google has no API for shopping list while Alexa does... I guess its time to sell my Google Home

Answer (score 0):

You can get the JSON from this endpoint, assuming you're authenticated.  You'll have to pass the cookie and maybe a few other headers - not sure.  But, it could get the job done...

Sign into your account and go to https://shoppinglist.google.com.  From there, open up your networking tab in your dev console, check the requests.  You'll see one called `lookup`:

`https://shoppinglist.google.com/u/0/_/list/textitem/lookup`

The query params are important for auth.  I don't know how auth works here and if you can easily hit it or not, but it's there, the JSON in the request.  You'll just need to auth and pass the right query params.

Comment: Could you elaborate as i can't get that link of yours to work?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The current app seems SSR; it does no api calls.

Comment: @billy It's probably been updated since this comment was originally posted.

Answer (score -1):

You can export shopping lists in a CSV format using https://takeout.google.com. A download link can be emailed or a file can be dropped in Drive, Dropbox etc. This can be configured to export every two months for 1 year.

The data contains the name of the item, the quantity, if it is checked or not, and any additional notes.

Answer (score -8):

(Almost?) All public software products of Google have some sort of API. 
Thumb rule: You can access the product via app, website or similar? Then there will be an API.

You can however create a thread over on googles suggestion site and request an api for the shopping list, if no one has done so. :)

Comment: While this is true, many of their products (such as this one) don't have a public API, so this isn't particularly useful for most cases. I guess you could inspect the web traffic to reverse engineer the API