# Google script for Google Keep

Tags: google-apps-script, google-keep

Is is possible to automatically share or unshare a Google Keep note using labels?
e.g. if I add label Sam to a note - share it automatically with Sam. If the label is removed them unshare it.

Kind regards,
Vijay

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196238/is-there-a-google-keep-api

Comment: Welcome. The question is unclear for this site. Please follow the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far Google Keep is not supported by Apps Script and any Google API, but there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36760910) for it on Public Issue Tracker.

You can give it a "star" to increase visibility.

Comment: Google Keep API - https://developers.google.com/keep/api/reference/rest/v1/notes/list

Comment: There's no API for `Google Keep` that could be leveraged for personal usage (as GAS can be), right? The link above states it's available for Enterprise environments. I don't use `Keep` much, but it does have the advantage of being able to be written to by way of verbal Google Assistant commands. Ultimately I'm trying to create a situation where if I say something like,  "hey google, log that I did 5 pushups" (not to brag), I'd like that metric to be added to KEEP, then have some recurring event perhaps in GAS scan for such items and ultimately log in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Google marked the [original feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760910?pli=1) completed but only enable Keep API for Enterprise use. New [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201708488) tracks Personal gmail accounts.